# Why do assembly programs use the register indirect addressing mode when they don't need to?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

In what follows below, I use a generic assembly language as is done in my text (*Computer Organization and Embedded Systems*, 6e, by Hamacher et al.).

Consider the code snippet below which is the setup to calling a subroutine which is to compare two lists of bytes (byte-wise) for equality. The specific application is irrelevant to my question though.

```
Move R2, #N
Load R2, (R2)
Move R3, #FIRST   
Move R4, #SECOND
Call MEMCMP
.
.
.
```

From a backgrouund point of view, imagine that we have the number of entries $n$ in the given list stored at memory location `N` and that the two lists to be compared have their first elements at locations `FIRST` and `SECOND`.

My question is about the

```
Move R2, #N
Load R2, (R2)
```

sequence specifically. Why use two instructions (i.e. why go through the register indirect addressing mode) rather than just using `Load R2, N` (i.e. the absolute addressing mode). I think there must be a good reason to do this since the authors do this repeatedly but, after scouring my book, I can't find a good answer. Does it have something to do with the absolute addressing mode causing difficulties in terms of fitting the whole address into the instruction?

To be clear, I have no confusion about what `N` etc. actually are. They are parsed by assemblers and replaced with the actual *number* corresponding to the given memory address. I am instead wondering about why the given choice of addressing mode is made even when it's apparently not necessary.

Comment: The architecture may not even *have* a "load absolute" instruction.  If the instruction size is the same as the address size (common on RISC architectures), then there simply isn't enough room to fit a full address into an instruction, and still have any room for opcode bits.  On such an architecture, the "move immediate" would have the same problem - but that can be easily split into two actual instructions (loading the low and high halves of the register separately, perhaps).

Comment: That makes sense, and I suspect that's what's going on. The MoveImmediate is really a pseudoinstruction then, as you say. I'd be happy to accept an answer to that effect, thanks so much! @jasonharper

Comment: @jasonharper: Or perhaps `#N` in this case happens to be a small integer that fits in an immediate, because this program knows where it's going to load in memory.  An ISA like RISC-V with a zero register could use `lw $t0, N($zero)` to do a load-absolute in terms of its one addressing mode (`reg + imm12`), but there are ISAs like ARM without a zero register which also don't have load-absolute.

Comment: (ARM has load PC-relative so if you're willing to use special-case code/data layout, you'd arrange for that instead.  But if not, yeah to load from an absolute address that fits in an immediate, `mov r0, #0x4000` / `ldr r0, [r0]`.  ARM immediates are 8-bit plus an even rotate count, so can actually encode non-tiny numbers if they're round.)

Comment: Touche, thanks very much for all the info, @PeterCordes . Definitely lots for me to learn yet as I'm still learning about very generic assembly/ISA choices :)

Comment: In MIPS most assemblers you can write `lw $t0,N`, But the processor doesn't have this instruction, though the assemblers helpfully consider that has meaning and interpret as a pseudo instruction, which expands to something like `la $t0,N; lw $t0,0(t0)` (ymmv, depending on the assembler).